# Rails - passing an id for a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-success"  id="btn_renew" onclick="lo_items_navigate('<%= renew_account_lo_item_path(@account, :id => 0) %>');"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> <%= t('toolbar.renew_label') %></button>
```

I also have a checkbox for each row in the table.  The user can only choose one checkbox (I have to use checkboxes).

If the user checks a checkbox, then the button becomes visible and they can click it.  But how do I get and pass the id for that item in the table into the Rails URL?

For this part:

```
onclick="loa_items_navigate('<%= renew_account_loa_item_path(@account, :id => 0) %>')
```

My id is listed in the checkboxes like this:

```
 <input class="select"  type="checkbox" data_value="<%= lo_item.id  %>" />
```

How do I populate id>?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually add a `data-url` attribute, and write some simple js plugin, that would listen to the `click` event, and make a ajax request to the url from the `data-url` attribute

If you already have a `data-id` attribute (should be with a dash actually, not with the underscore), you can do this:

```
<input class="select" type="checkbox" data-id="<%= lo_item.id %>" />
<button data-url="/url/:id" data-trigger="navigate-to-item" >

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[data-trigger*="navigate-to-item"]').click(function(event) {
    id = $('input.select:checked').data('id');
    url = $(event.target).data('url').replace(':id', id);

    // and here you can do something with your url
  });
})
```

Comment: I have this in my checkbox inputs:     <input class="select"  type="checkbox" data_value="<%= loa_item.id  %>" />  where to go from here?

Comment: i added a small example

Comment: thanks so does my onclick on the button disappear - could you change your example to match my button code?

Comment: yep, i would just delete the `onclick`, it's not the best way to handle events anyway

Comment: when i add in code to navigate to the url, I get this as my url:  http://localhost:3000/url/12

Comment: well, you should change this part from my example: `<button data-url="/url/:id"`, i wrote the url there just to give you an example :)

Comment: can I do it in the JS like this?  url = ('<%= renew_account_loa_item_path(@account, :id) %>').replace(':id', id);

Comment: only if this js will be in your .erb template, but i would suggest to pass the url via the `data-attribute`

Comment: almost got it but my url is now:  http://localhost:3000/accounts/400/'/accounts/400/lo_items/12/renew';  here is my data-url:   data-url="'<%= renew_account_lo_item_path(@account, :id) %>';"

Comment: I think I got it, great help

Comment: you just need to remove the `'` and the `;` from the data-url, like that: `data-url="<%= renew_account_lo_item_path(@account, :id) %>"`